# How to compile a simple Command-line OCaml script into Javascript

Tags: javascript, ocaml, js-of-ocaml

I have a simple command line OCaml application that performs a computation on `Sys.argv.(1)` and outputs the result to stdout. I can compile it to Javascript with `js_of_ocaml`, but it gives me a lot of errors about `caml_ml_output_char` being undefined. I fixed those errors by stubbing out the printfs, so it runs, but it freezes firefox while running.

How can I cleanly compile simple OCaml command-line script into a Javascript based webpage; without maintaining a forked version or freezing the browser?

Answer (score 3):

You will probably want to use webworkers, as running software not designed around Javascript's co-operative multi-tasking in the UI thread can cause the browser to lock up. 
You can add the following header to the top of your OCaml file to overload the normal OCaml Sys and print implementations

```
(* JsHeader.ml *)
let output_buffer_ = Buffer.create 1000
let flush x=let module J = Js.Unsafe in let () = J.call 
        (J.variable "postMessage") (J.variable "self")
        [|J.inject (Js.string (Buffer.contents output_buffer_))|]
     in Buffer.clear output_buffer_

let print_string = Buffer.add_string output_buffer_
let print_char = Buffer.add_char output_buffer_
let print_newline () = print_char '\n'
let print_endline s = print_string (s^"\n"); flush ()
let caml_ml_output_char = print_char
let printf fmt = Printf.bprintf output_buffer_ fmt
module Printf = struct
    include Printf
    let printf fmt = Printf.bprintf output_buffer_ fmt
end
```

The most natural way to pass in commandline arguments is through the URL sent to the web worker. We can override the Ocaml Sys module to instead read `?argv` as a sequence of null terminated strings.

```
module Sys = struct
    let char_split delim s = (*Str.split is overkill*)
        let hd = ref "" in let l = ref [] in 
        String.iter (fun c -> 
            if c = delim
            then  (l := (!hd)::(!l); hd := "")
            else hd := (!hd) ^ (String.make 1 c)
        ) s;
        List.rev ((!hd)::(!l)) 
    let getenv x = List.assoc x Url.Current.arguments
    let argv = Array.of_list (char_split '\x00' (getenv "?argv"))
    let executable_name = argv.(0)
end
```

Now that we have entered the header we can enter a simple OCaml Command Line program:

```
(* cli.ml *)
let _ = print_string (Array.fold_left (^) "" (Array.make 40 (String.lowercase (Sys.argv.(1)^"\n"))) )
```

This command line program relies on the OS to flush the output, but we will have to manually flush the output. 
You may also want to send a null character so the Javascript knows that the command has finished.
This can be achieved by appending the following footer.

```
(* JsFooter.ml *)
let _ = flush stdout; print_endline "\x00"
```

We can join the files and compile them as follows:

```
 cat JsHeader.ml cli.ml JsFooter.ml > merged.ml
 ocamlbuild -use-menhir -menhir "menhir" \
   -pp "camlp4o -I /opt/local/lib/ocaml/site-lib js_of_ocaml/pa_js.cmo" \
   -cflags -I,+js_of_ocaml,-I,+site-lib/js_of_ocaml -libs js_of_ocaml \
   -lflags -I,+js_of_ocaml,-I,+site-lib/js_of_ocaml merged.byte
 js_of_ocaml merged.byte
```

Now that we have created the file merged.js we can wrap the javascript in a simple web page such as the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ml2js sample_cli</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var worker;
function go () {
  var output=document.getElementById ("output");
  var argv = encodeURIComponent("/bin/sample_cli\0"+document.getElementById ("input").value);
  if (worker) {
    worker.terminate();
  }
  worker = new Worker ("sample_cli.js?argv="+argv);
  document.getElementById ("output").value="";
  worker.onmessage = function (m) {
    if (typeof m.data == 'string') {
    if (m.data == "\0\n") {
        output.scrollTop = output.scrollHeight
    } else {
        output.value+=m.data;
    }
    }
  }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body onload=go()>
<textarea id="input" rows="2" cols="60" onkeyup="go()" onchange="go()" style="width:90%">SAMPLE_INPUT</textarea> 
<button onclick="go()">go</button><br>
<textarea id="output" rows="0" cols="60" style="width:100%;height:90%" readonly onload=go()>
Your browser does not seem to support Webworkers.
Try Firefox, Chrome or IE10+. 
</textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

See http://www.dansted.org/app/bctl-plain.html for an example of this approach in action, and https://github.com/gmatht/TimeLogicUnify/blob/master/ATL/js/webworker/ml2js.sh for a script that appends the appropriate headers, footers etc.

Answer (score 1):

What js_of_ocaml's version are you using ? You should not get errors with caml_ml_output_char. When running on node, you should have sys.argv set correctly. In the browser, Sys.argv is set to [|"a.out"|].
Please open a GitHub issue on https://github.com/ocsigen/js_of_ocaml/issues/new if you still have an issue with this.

Comment: I am using 1.4-1build1 on Ubuntu. Even if later versions of `js_of_ocaml` have done a better job stubbing out of e.g. Sys.argv presumably I'll still need to wrap my ml script similarly to above to make it actually useful in a browser? (BTW, this is probably better as a comment than an answer?)

Comment: I have modified my question to mention I am specifically interested in a web-page.